# If I lived in Canada (with EU passport) could I visit the US often?

Tags: visas, usa, canada, repeat-visits

If I got a working holiday visa for Canada (with Italian passport), would it be possible for me to visit the US often like once a month for a few days (< 1 week)?

Would it be different if I traveled by plane or bus?

My main concern is that I could be denied access at the US border because of officials being suspicious of my frequent traveling.

Comment: Why not? There are plenty of people who come across the border and go back every day.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I read there are some limitations on the frequency of the traveling. Somewhere it says a person with ESTA for the US should stay in Canada for a relatively long period of time to be counted as a reset of the given 90 days.

Maybe what you say could be possible for Canadian citizens.

Comment: That does not apply to Canadian _residents_.

Comment: Is the exception for _permanent_ residents? I don't think a working holiday visa would qualify.

Comment: Not to mention, the so-called "90 day rule" is widely misunderstood. It is to prevent visa runs, not short visits. You have a temporary resident visa in Canada, so it doesn't apply to you anyway as long as you return to Canada when you visit the US.

Comment: @Cress the exception applies to anyone who resides in Canada, not only those who have permanent resident status.

Comment: Are you a Canadian permanent resident. If so, and if you have lived in Canada for > 3 years, you can and should apply for NEXUS card which will allow you to frequently travel between US and Canada. In fact, NEXUS card is ideal for frequent US-Canada travelers (by land, air or sea).
Also, rather than being more suspicious, the US officials will be less suspicious since you are a frequent traveler and the chances of you stayin in the US are fewer, as long as you stick to the purpose of the trip that you declare.